# grails run-app error (TNS:listener: all appropriate instances are in restricted mode)

Tags: grails, groovy, tns

I started my application in the usual way with the following command `grails -Dgrails.env=local run-app -https` but today I ended up with a unique error - **TNS:listener: all appropriate instances are in restricted mode**. The information I found regarding this error is that the database has been started in restricted mode from [here](http://oraclequirks.blogspot.com/2008/03/ora-12526-tnslistener-all-appropriate.html). All I have in my `datasource.groovy` is this:

```
local {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
```

Can you help me figure out what might be the problem? I can attach the log file if you need further information.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an Oracle JDBC URL, it's an H2 URL. I assume that you are specifying the Oracle driver and/or dialect in the top-level `dataSource` block, so that's why it's starting to talk to Oracle. Change the url to one that makes sense (e.g. `url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"` or some other that you know works outside of Grails).

You probably don't want to be using `create-drop` unless this is a new schema or one that you own. If it's an existing database that you're trying to connect to and work with but not change, use any value for `dbCreate` other than one of the values listed in `DataSource.groovy`; my preference is `dbCreate = "none"` since it works to get Hibernate to not try to drop, create, or update anything, and it's self-documenting.